# Select count datediff in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2008, select, count, datediff

I'm having issues getting the desired results from my database. The `join_service_date` and `dropped_service_date` columns have dates. The rejects have an `r` in the column if it is rejected.

I want to be able to count the agents sales, rejects, dropped sales and how many of those sales have dropped our service within 0-30 days, 31-60 days or 61-90 days. I got the results I needed from doing several small queries, but I would like to learn or know how to gather the information in a just 1 or as little as possible queries.

Also how would I specify this for a specific month like march or april.

```
select agentid, 
       count(join_service_date), 
       count(dropped_service_date),
       count(rejects), 
       datediff(day, join_service_date, dropped_service_date)
from dbtable
group by agentid
```

Comment: Have you tried using GROUP BY or even any one of the conditionals (CASE/IF)?

Comment: No I haven't because I didn't know how to use the case/if conditionals

Comment: I recommend googling them.  Different dialects of SQL support different conditionals; the nice thing about them is you can include them within the parenthesis of your counts or other aggregates...